# Can not create new object - create() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Tags: django

I am trying to create new object from values served from form. Here is the code:

```
def issue_save(request):
    issue = Issue.objects.create(IssueForm(request.POST))
    issue.save(commit=True)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("main.views.index"))
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

TypeError at /problemy/pridat/ulozit/
create() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/problemy/pridat/ulozit/
Django Version: 1.2.3
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:
create() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
Exception Location: views.py in issue_save, line 20

Code on line 20:

```
issue = Issue.objects.create(IssueForm(request.POST))
```

I'm really stuck here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't tell us what exactly is `IssueForm`. If it's a `ModelForm`, you can use its `.save` method instead:

```
IssueForm(request.POST).save()
```

If it's a regular form, use this:

```
issue = Issue.objects.create(**IssueForm(request.POST).cleaned_data)
```

***Note:** `**` is argument unpacking (see [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists))*

Comment: If it's not a ModelForm, it should be, seeing as the OP is trying to create a model instance directly from it.